# Bug in Lightning Button Base Component with `afterRender` in Spring 17

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bug, spring17, lightning-base-component

Having an `afterRender` in a `Lightning Component` makes the Icon not show in Lightning Base Component `<lightning:button />`

Here is a quick Test App:

**TestApp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:TestComponent />
</aura:application>
```

**TestComponent.component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="string" />

    <lightning:button type="button" variant="neutral" label="Download" title="Download" iconName="utility:download" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.clickMe}" />

</aura:component>
```

**TestComponentRenderer.js**

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {

    }
})
```

If we remove the `afterRender` function, the button icon only displays if I remove the `afterRender` function completely from renderer.js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I belive that is happening because you are overriding the `afterRender` method and you are not calling the `superAfterRender` method.

The following code will work fine.

`TestComponentRenderer.js`

```
afterRender: function (component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    // interact with the DOM here
}
```

This way you will be extending the default rendering functionality. [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm)